# Mapreduce result don't fit memory

Tags: matlab, mapreduce, bigdata

I need to calculate 10^6x10^6 correlation matrix. To do so I use `mapreduce` and instructions from [the official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/using-mapreduce-to-compute-covariance-and-related-quantities.html).

My main script:

```
ds=datastore('\data\','Type','Tall');  
outds=mapreduce(ds,@covarianceMapper, @covarianceReducer);  
results = readall(outds); 
CorrelationMatrix = results.Value{1};
```

Mapper function:

```
function covarianceMapper(t,~,intermKVStore)
    x=t;
    n = size(x,1);
    m = mean(x,1);
    c = cov(x,1);
    add(intermKVStore,'key',{n m c})
end
```

Reducer function:

```
function covarianceReducer(~,intermValIter,outKVStore)
n1 = 0; % no rows so far
m1 = 0; % mean so far
c1 = 0; % covariance so far

while hasnext(intermValIter)
    % Get the next chunk, and extract the count, mean, and covariance
    t = getnext(intermValIter);
    n2 = t{1};
    m2 = t{2};
    c2 = t{3};

    % Use weighting formulas to update the values so far
    n = n1+n2;                     % new count
    m = (n1*m1 + n2*m2) / n;       % new mean

    % New covariance is a weighted combination of the two covariance, plus
    % additional terms that relate to the difference in means
    c1 = (n1*c1 + n2*c2 + n1*(m1-m)'*(m1-m) + n2*(m2-m)'*(m2-m))/ n;

    % Store the new mean and count for the next iteration
    m1 = m;
    n1 = n;
end

% Save results in the output key/value store
s=sqrt(diag(c1));
add(outKVStore,'correlation',c1./(s*s'));
end
```

The problem is that the size of `ds` is 10^6 (columns) X 10^3 (rows). Resulting correlation matrix is huge (10^6x10^6) and I have problems with memory on reducer step. Such a huge result, obviously, don't fit my RAM and I have a mistake. I understand that I should play around tall arrays, but simple `tall(mapreduce())` did not help.

**As `mapreduce()` designed for big data their should be a solution when output is also big. Could you help me to find such solution?**

Comment: Either buy more RAM, or calculate in chunks and write to disc after each chunk. MATLAB will not be able to load the matrix completely, but reading it has to be done in chunks as well then.

Comment: But with tall array matlab may.